# PHP: Returning Data to a Web page

Tags: php, html

I have an application that returns data to a PHP/HTML file but the issue is it can call my application many times per page load:

An example HTML file with my calls only asking for images:

```
<img border="0" alt="" src="http://mydomain.com/test/index.php?element=1"></img>
</br>
<img border="0" alt="" src="http://mydomain.com/test/index.php?element=2"></img>
</br>
<img border="0" alt="" src="http://mydomain.com/test/index.php?element=3"></img>
</br>
```

This works fine every time and all of the images are returned, however my trouble starts when I want to return text/html.

The server side code works fine:

```
header('Content-type: text/html');
ob_start();
echo $filepath;
ob_flush();
ob_end_clean();
```

$filepath contains some text or HTML such as, "`Check out our <strong>NEW</strong> offers!`"

All I want is to return the HTML text and allow it to be embedded within the page so that if they want:

```
<h1>Check out our <strong>NEW</strong> offers!</h1>
```

or

```
<p>Check out our <strong>NEW</strong> offers!</p>
```

It will work fine.

The problem is, which HTML Tag should I use to call for the data in the same way I use `<img>` for images?

I have tried `<object>`, `

---

` etc... but these are no good as all I want is the raw HTML data returned.

Using the Javascript load() is not good as it relies on the web page builder creating a function call for every time they want to get data.

Comment: You can do it by Ajax.

Comment: Did any of the below answers resolve your question? Please can you accept an answer if so and up vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with HTML, you could use jQuery + AJAX.

Comment: I thought as much but I do not like the way it loads AFTER the page has been initially rendered when I use the load() function!  Is there a away to get it to load before?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Ajax. you cannot do it in html.

Answer (score 0):

You can output it with PHP and then if you update the file it will update site wide without making changes everywhere. Is there a reason you want to do it this way and not just insert the code manually? This could cause problems with the caching of your pages depending on how dynamic they are.

```
newOffers.php

<?php
    echo '<h1>Check out our <strong>NEW</strong> offers!</h1>';
?>
```

Then in your site source:

```
<p>Blah blah blah...</p>
<?php include 'newOffers.php'; ?>
<p>Click our new offers link above</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `<iframe>` for this, but this is not really ideal as the resizing is not done automatically.

Alternatively you can indeed use Ajax to change the code.

Either way: think about your reason for wanting to include the HTML like this instead of just returning this html code with the original return?